# Why did Deckard get a citation from his police department?

Tags: do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

In Philip K. Dick's **Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?** why did Deckard get a citation at the end from his police department? Because he retired too many andys in a single day? I thought the police wants to retire as many as possible. Sounds to me like he should get a bonus.

Comment: Your third question is easy: a citation is a good thing not a criticism. Deckard got the citation for good work i.e. retiring six replicants in a day.

Comment: "Confusing a heck" is not a real question. The other 3 should be split (though, as John Rennie said, the third is simply a misunderstanding of the word "citation"). As for question 2, I don't know if interpretation of deliberately obscure literary works is within the scope of this site :)

Comment: @FixedPoint The intent of this platform is to find good answers to specific questions. Adding multiple questions makes it less likely that an answer will be great for all of the questions. As for where it is listed... [here is a very recent discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/why-should-this-question-be-split).  It is also listed in the faq in the section on [closed questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#close) ("overly broad"). The feedback being offered is an attempt to help you get better answers, so please don't interpret them as personal attacks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. As a moderator, let me point you to a few aspects of our site. This is a [questions and answers site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/about), not a discussion forum. We therefore expect a question to be a *question* and not a jumble of loosely related questions. We also expect questions to have meaningful titles. Other people [can edit your posts](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#editing), and here they have done so to help make your post suitable; do not revert their edits and do not berate them for it — [be nice](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette).

Comment: Just like how I mentioned in the deleted comments, they were specific concrete questions. I wasn't looking for discussions or anything. And it was not a jumble and they weren't loosely related. Editing by others is fine but my post was changed entirely without asking me or even notifying me and I find that entirely unmannerly. I see that there is no clearly written defined policy about this anywhere. How was I supposed to know this?

Comment: I put the questions together, people get upset. I ask separate questions in a short amount of time then I'll get downvoted because I am spamming. And if I feel like the edit was unjustified and changes what I meant, I will revert it. Its my post and if anyone has a problem with it, let me know and I'll fix it. All of this should be specified in the FAQ or something. And I was being nice while making it clear how meaningless it is and how annoying it was. However I am done with this, I won't say any more on this. I have already conceded.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He *was* being rewarded.

[Merriam-Webster's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/citation) of "Citation":

> 1 : an official summons to appear (as before a court)
>
> 2
>
> - a : an act of quoting; especially : the citing of a previously settled case at law
> - b : excerpt, quotation
>
> 3: mention: as
>
> - a : **a formal statement of the achievements of a person receiving an academic honor**
> - b : **specific reference in a military dispatch to meritorious performance of duty**
>
> ---
>
> Examples of CITATION
>
> - He was issued a citation.
> - He received a citation for reckless driving.
> - **gave her a citation for bravery**

The word "citation" can be either positive *or* negative depending on context.

Answer (score 8):

Like user [John Rennie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4144/john-rennie) said in a comment, Deckard got a citation because he "retired" (i.e. executed) six androids, which was a remarkable feat. A citation is another word for commendation, so that's a good thing.

Excerpt from the book:

> A moment later the orange, triangular face of Ann Marsten appeared on the screen. "Oh,  Mr. Deckard — Inspector Bryant has been trying to get hold of you. **I think he's turning your name over to Chief Cutter for a citation. Because you retired those six** — "
>
> "I know what I did," he said.
>
> "**That's never happened before**. Oh, and Mr. Deckard; your wife phoned. She wants to know if you're all right. Are you all right?"